# "Invalid column name" for all columns in a table error after migrating to .net core 5.0 (from 2.2)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have recently upgraded to .net core 5.0, which created so many errors in my code. One of them is the `Invalid column name` error for all columns in the `Submissions` table. I checked my table and all columns are properly defined in the database. The code is below, the `Include()` statement loads the `Submissions`:

```
  IQueryable<StudentGroup> groups = _context.StudentGroups
                              .Include(sg => sg.Submissions)                                  
                              .Skip(offset)
                              .Take(pagesize);
```

I have already user data in my database, so I prefer not to delete the database and re-run `Create-Database`. Any ideas?

Detailed error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'.
> Invalid colum name 'AssessedByEveryone'.
> Invalid column name 'DateCreated'.
> Invalid column name 'GoogleDriveDialogueFileId'.
> Invalid column name 'GoogleDriveOriginalFileId'.
> Invalid column name 'GoogleDriveReadFileId'.
> Invalid column name 'GoogleDriveReviseFileId'.
> Invalid column name 'ReviewRoundId'.
> Invalid column name 'StudentGroupId'.
> Invalid column name 'StudentId'.
> Invalid column name 'Title'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__169_0(Task
> result)`Invalid column

Below is the `Submission` entity:

```
public class Submission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string GoogleDriveOriginalFileId { get; set; }
    public string GoogleDriveReadFileId { get; set; }
    public string GoogleDriveDialogueFileId { get; set; }
    public string GoogleDriveReviseFileId { get; set; }
    public bool AssessedByEveryone { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string StudentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentGroupId")]
    public StudentGroup StudentGroup { get; set; }
    public int StudentGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReviewRoundId")]
    public ReviewRound ReviewRound { get; set; }
    public int ReviewRoundId { get; set; }

}
```

Below is the `StudentGroup` entity:

```
public class StudentGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsPeerReviewGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } //set to false when deleted by the instructor
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupReviewing")]
    public IEnumerable<PeerReviewAssignment> AsServingReviewer { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("GroupReviewed")]
    public IEnumerable<PeerReviewAssignment> AsServingStudentGroup { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }//submissions for different reviewrounds or assignments by the same group [to make it more flexible]

    public IEnumerable<GroupMembership> GroupMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

Here is he Submssions table in the database:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an error? And entity StudentGroups and Submissions

Comment: @VovaBilyachat I added the details Thanks!

Comment: Also can you add screen of the table Submission

Comment: Before upgrade did you have custom column names ?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat I added the table. What do you mean by custom column names?

Comment: Never mind about custom columns. Other question are you sure you are using right connection string ?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat yes I am sure. I guess I have to re-create the database...

Comment: Why in Submission there is no ApplicationUserId?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232376/discussion-between-renakre-and-vova-bilyachat).

Comment: That's weird. Did you check the generated query? Maybe EFCore is targeting the wrong table. It is a long shot, but maybe you could run sp_tables and check if migration created other unexpected tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use IEnumerable instead of IQueryable. A weird behaviour.

Comment: Specify: did you change `IQueryable<StudentGroup> groups` to `IEnumerable<StudentGroup> groups`? | What do you do next with this query? How do you materialize it?